# How to assign an SNMPv2c inform request from another manager to the proper agent?

Tags: snmp

The SNMPv2c specification states that "An InformRequest-PDU is generated and transmitted at the request of an application in a SNMPv2 entity acting in a manager role..." [RFC 1905, section 4.2.7]

If a manager receives an inform request from another manager, I wonder how it assigns the data to the proper agent.

When the inform request is received from an agent - like a trap - the IP address can be used to assign the data to the agent.

This case also seems to make more sense to me. Are there any real world applications where an inform is sent by a manager?

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the IP address in **INFORM PDU**. This type of SNMP PDU does not have such field. So the receiver always uses **src_ip** of UDP datagram. The Agent Address is part of **TrapV1 PDU** only.

Comment: I know that the inform PDU does not have an address field. The question is how to assign the data of an inform PDU to an agent if the src_ip of the UDP datagram is not the IP address of any of the agents (i.e. the request comes from another manager).

Comment: There is no way to do this based on INFORM. You should use TRAPv1 for trap forwarding.

Comment: I don't want to forward traps. I am just trying to understand who can send traps and informs to know whether my manager can collect them per agent or globally.

Comment: Nowadays INFORMs are widely used for the same purpose as SNMP traps. So the agent acts as originator and the manager acts as receiver. As you probably know they do provide reliable delivery mechanism.